# index.php and Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

Hi I have found the answer i was looking for have managed to set Web Server Rewrites to Yes and now my website is showing all URLs without the index.php so happy days.

My problem and question is why when I enter a url from my website with the index.php in the url it shows the url with index.php and does not redirect to the url without index.php. This is driving me crazy, does anyone know how to fix this.

So if you go to this url: http://www.glamairsupplies.co.uk you can see if you browse around the store index.php is not used at all.

URL's are shown like this:

http://www.glamairsupplies.co.uk/abrasives-products.html

But if you add index.php to the url and type in:
http://www.glamairsupplies.co.uk/index.php/abrasives-products.html

It does this for every page and i think i am getting penalised by google for duplicate content. I can not find what I need to do to remove this as. I have tried several different forum posts to edit htaccess file to do what I want and i just cant get it to do it.

Anyone please?

Comment: Can you show us your .htaccess?

Comment: I have duplicated it here: http://www.glamairsupplies.co.uk/htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior.
Magento just tries it's best to parse the URL.
You will not be penalised by google for duplicate content.
What do you expect `http://glamairsupplies.co.uk/index.php/abrasives-products.html` to show?

Error page or 404? Do you think it would be a correct behavior?

You should leave it as it is. If there is no more place where the links containing 'index.php' are generated, Google will 'forget' the soon.

Comment: no i just wanted to to redirect to http://glamairsupplies.co.uk/abrasives-products.html so that the index.php is not shown, if you are 100% sure there is no danger of duplicate content then i am not so bothered. You think it is all good?

Comment: @DanDavies I just have checked some of my websites on Magento and discovered that they work same way (with index.php too). And I got no problems about duplicate content.

Comment: Far-Behind-Sight 1000% observation on this is to always to set **Web Server Rewrites** to **Yes** before coming out of development and allowing any search engine to index your website. If you have the canonicals turned on in System Config, there's no penalization for dupes.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was confused about "Web Server Rewrites".. To make it clear,

Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Search Engines Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites set to yes

And then,

System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache